# Feature creation of Print module for path to print stylesheet

Tags: 7

Using the [print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print), I need to create a Feature to deploy in order to set the path to the .css file to my themes directory on my production site.

In Features, what do I need to check to make sure I get these settings?

When creating the Features, the closest thing I can find is a checkbox under permissions:
[image: Print Permissions]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need [strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) enabled to export the path variable. Then it will be available as `print_css` variable.

[image]